# How to ignore lines that cannot be split in 3 columns in Java?

Tags: java, file, split, bufferedreader

I have a file that's read as such:

```
James#Smith#777-888
Lucas#Fisher#888-666
Marie#Holmes
```

and I want my Java program to ignore lines that do not contain the 3 elements (name, surname, phone number).
I cannot find a way to integrate this information to my code below. Any thoughts?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Atzendaa 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\file.txt"));
          
            ArrayList <String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList <String> surname = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList <String> phone = new ArrayList<String>();
            
            String line = br.readLine();
            while(line!=null)
            {
                String[] del = line.split("#");
                surname.add(del[0]);
                name.add(del[1]);
                phone.add(del[2]);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            br.close(); 
            System.out.println(surname);
            System.out.println(name);
            System.out.println(phone);
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Problem reading from file");
        }
    }
```

Comment: may be check, if the line contains two `#` before splitting the line?

Comment: or check if `del.length < 3`?

Comment: thank you for ansering but an entry of a file could as well be : James#Din

Comment: May be you can use regular expressions to match the pattern and if matched pattern is true you can proceed or ignore that line. You can refer, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an if condition to check,

```
if (del.length == 3)
```

if the string array length is 3

```
while(line!=null)
    {
        String[] del = line.split("#");
        if (del.length == 3)
        {
            surname.add(del[0]);
            name.add(del[1]);
            phone.add(del[2]);
        }            
        line = br.readLine();
    }
```